Can I use a simple rain diverter to direct water into the gutter?

Water has ruined the skirt board and siding because it runs off the roof and right down the wall since the gutter doesn't go all the way to the end of the house.
Besides replacing the entire gutter I was thinking on the roof I could put a rain diverter to point the water in the direction of the gutter.
Would this work or should I just replace the entire gutter?

Try reversing the bend in the piece of flashing that's bent up, and possibly extending it.  Does the edge of the flashing overlap the gutter?

The wall and skirt board don't look ruined. Just a bit dirty.  But a new diverter will help.

The skirt board is rather grotty and is on its way to "ruined" simply because it's wood sitting directly on the shingles. Every time it rains, the bottom of that wood is sitting on wet shingles. When the time comes, replace it with a slightly narrower piece (maybe 1/4") and leave the gap at the bottom so the wood and the shingles can dry out. Also, make sure that it's well primed/painted on all 6 sides.

Sorry, the skirt board on the ground (not in the photo) is rotted out because all this water falls directly onto it and not in the gutter

Extend the gutter to the wall

@FreeMan might also consider using a PVC board there instead of wood!

A metal sheet curved or bent to shape can be used to promote the flow away from the wall and into the gutter.
It seems that there the remains of some metal bits under the tile in the corner - perhaps the original diverter got removed or lost when cleaning.
